# Data mining with python(pandas) (data Cleaning)

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Please, can any one help me out, i am new to data mining and i am looking for a way to add BaltimoreWashington and Baltimore-Washington including its values and as one and also to make Denver become just one and adding all its values in to one.(Data Cleaning)
Please, see data below for better understanding..

```
df3=pd.read_sql_query('select * from avocado', con=engine)
df3["region"].value_counts()
```

```
Tampa                   169
Northeast               169
Sacramento              169
NewYork                 169
Plains                  169
Jacksonville            169
Orlando                 169
Boston                  169
Portland                169
Nashville               169
StLouis                 169
LasVegas                169
DallasFtWorth           169
SanDiego                169
Midsouth                169
BuffaloRochester        169
RichmondNorfolk         169
TotalUS                 169
NorthernNewEngland      169
Albany                  169
Chicago                 169
Seattle                 169
Spokane                 169
SouthCentral            169
West                    169
Southeast               169
GreatLakes              169
Atlanta                 169
Detroit                 169
Houston                 169
SouthCarolina           169
CincinnatiDayton        169
LosAngeles              169
Syracuse                169
GrandRapids             169
Philadelphia            169
PhoenixTucson           169
HartfordSpringfield     169
HarrisburgScranton      169
California              169
Indianapolis            169
Boise                   169
MiamiFtLauderdale       169
RaleighGreensboro       169
Louisville              169
Charlotte               169
Pittsburgh              169
SanFrancisco            169
Columbus                169
Roanoke                 169
NewOrleansMobile        169
WestTexNewMexico        167
Denver                  100
BaltimoreWashington      89
Baltimore-Washington     80
 Denver                  50
 Denver                  19
Name: region, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df["region"] = df["region"].str.replace("-", "").str.replace(" ", "")`?

Comment: Thanks very much sir, you are blessed for ever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand your data format. Your cities are basically categories represented as string, so value_counts() counts population for each category, once again based on string representation.

So you have at least two options to merge you categories.
First you can change the string representation of your issued categories. Basically replace "-" with"" for Washington, and " " with "" for Denver.

Or you can find in your datamart (if it exists) a different representation of your categories, less sensitive to typos, like closed numeric categories. It's all about data quality here, you can parse your data if your splitted category is indeed splitted for every representation.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for the command line to accomplish this in paython

Comment: Stack overflow community is here to give you the way to do it, not to do your job :)
If you want to solve your string matching issue, assuming you want to keep using pandas, replace can be the way to go : 

[Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Trying to match string is a quick solution. The best way would be to go deeper in your database and first be sure that this string representation is the best you can get.